# Shopware: htaccess authentication not working with adminnistration

Tags: .htaccess, shopware, shopware6

I'm trying to set a password authentication in my Shopware 6 application, I created a `.htpasswd` file with the username and a hashed password.

The `.htpasswd` was linked properly with the .htaccess and it works as I can see the prompt dialog asking for the username/password combination.

My `public/.htaccess` file:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted area"
AuthUserFile /Path/to/MyDomainSecretDirectory/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

**The problem:** When trying to access the `/admin` the dialogue box keeps asking for the password and returns a 401 error although the password is fine and works with the storefront.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to this issue.

> With Shopware 6, some of the shop data is also outside of the
> directory that can be accessed from the Internet. With a classic
> `.htaccess` password protection setup, the Shopware login no longer
> works. When calling up the Shopware backend, you are repeatedly asked
> for the password for the htaccess protection, making it impossible to
> log in.

The solution here is to unprotect the `/api` endpoint. Simply add the following code block under the `.htaccess` code:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted area"
AuthUserFile /Path/to/MyDomainSecretDirectory/.htpasswd
require valid-user

# ADD THESE LINES TO UNPROTECT THE /API ROUTE
SetEnvIf Request_URI /api noauth=1
<RequireAny>
Require env noauth
Require env REDIRECT_noauth
Require valid-user
</RequireAny>
```